# Powershell Adding users within groups to cross forest groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory-group

This script works without error now, but the problem is that when several groups in the searchbase are found, the script will add all users from all groups to the cross forest target groups.

So for example:

ForestAGroup1 = contains 2 users

ForestAGroup2 = contains 2 users

::runs script::

now...

ForestBGroup1 = contains 4 users

ForestBGroup2 = contains 4 users

The ForestBGroup1/2 needs to contain the same identical users as ForestAGroup1/2.

Here is the script for reference:

```
    $creds = Get-Credential
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Properties * -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=TEST,OU=Shop Print Groups,OU=User,OU=domain Groups,DC=domainA,DC=com" | export-csv c:\temp\test.csv
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Properties * -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=TEST,OU=Shop Print Groups,OU=User,OU=domain Groups,DC=domainA,DC=com"
Foreach($G In $Groups)
{
    #Display group members and group name
    Write-Host $G.Name
    Write-Host "-------------"
    $G.Members

    #Add members to domainB group
    $domainGMembers = import-csv C:\temp\test.csv | ForEach-Object -Process {Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.CN} | Select-Object samaccountname | export-csv c:\temp\gmembers.csv

    $domainDNUser = import-csv C:\temp\gmembers.csv | ForEach-Object -Process {Get-ADUser $_.samaccountname -Server "domainA.com" -properties:Distinguishedname}

    import-csv C:\temp\gmembers.csv | ForEach-Object -Process {Add-ADGroupMember -Server "domainB.com" -Identity $G.Name -Members $domainDNUser -Credential $creds -Verbose}

}
```

Comment: You should always clean your example for sensitive information. Remember that Contoso.com is a great company. The data now lives on in the history..

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say you want to have the same members in `ForestBGroup1` as you have in `ForestAGroup1` ("The ForestBGroup1/2 needs to contain the same identical users as ForestAGroup1/2."), but your example shows 2 members in A1 and 4 in B1. Having all members in all groups doesn't sound right, so my answer would only match A1 with B1 etc. If you really want all users in every B-group, then you should add them to one B-group and add that to the other B-groups. You don't want to maintain 10s of groups with identical members.

Comment: My example is clean of sensitive information, from what I can see? Yes, ForestAGroups1/2 should match identically to ForestBGroups1/2, but instead it is adding all users together to the destination ForestB groups.

Comment: It is now, but it wasn't when I wrote the comment (and the info is now in the edit history because you waited 5 mins before cleaning it). They add all users because that's what you have written it to do. You get all members from all groups in DomainA inside the foreach-loop, and then you add them to Group `$G.Name`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What are you doing?

- You export to csv, but still try to save it to a variable
- You search twice
- You add all members from ALL groups in `TEST`-OU to every group in `domainB`
- You waste time on saving and reading data that you already have in memory
- You search for the user-object to get `SamAccountName` when you already have something ten times better, the `DN`. Then you use that `SamAccountName` to find the `DN`.

Try this (untested):

```
$creds = Get-Credential
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Properties Members -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=TEST,OU=Shop Print Groups,OU=User,OU=domain Groups,DC=domain,DC=com"
Foreach($G In $Groups)
{
    #Display group members and group name
    Write-Host $G.Name
    Write-Host "-------------"
    $G.Members

    #Add members to domainB group
    $G.Members |
    Get-ADUser -Server fairfieldmfg.com |
    ForEach-Object { Add-ADGroupMember -Server "domainB.com" -Identity $G.Name -Members $_ -Credential $creds -Verbose }
}
```

I used a foreach-loop to run the `Add-ADGroupMember` because it usually fails in the middle of a group of members if it finds on the already is a member, but if we add them one at a time you get around that (or you could do a search and exclude those already in the group).

You may want to add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to `Add-ADGroupMember` to ignore those errors when you know the script works as it should.

Comment: You're missing the point that you must look-up each AD user from the source DomainA domain. Because your solution errors out with  "Cannot find an object with identity: blah blah" My solution may look clunky, but at least it doesn't error out at this point and manages to grab the correct objects. I'm just have a tough time getting them added to the correct groups now.

Comment: Added: `Get-ADUser $G.Members -Server fairfieldmfg.com -properties:Distinguishedname | ForEach-Object { Add-ADGroupMember -Server "dom02.net" -Identity $G.Name -Members $_ -Credential $creds -Verbose }` But this also fails with `Get-ADUser : Cannot convert 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported.`

Comment: I need the real error (switch out single words, not the entire message). Code should be added in the question, not in the comments..  As for the script. I'm not seing the problem.. The Groups is domainA, the members are domainA... You take the DomainA memberDNs from a group, search in domainA for samaccountname (waste), use that to search for DN in domaina (which you already had), and then you add to the domainb-group.. The only reason I can see skipping the two "get user samaccountname, then DN" being a problem is if ForestAGroup1 contains DomainB users.. Are there?

Comment: 1. The `Get-AdUser` step is not necessary. You already have the DN which is domain-unique. 2. If you really want to try that, try piping in the array.. `$G.Members | Get-ADUser -Server fairfieldmfg.com | ForEach-Object { Add-ADGroupMember -Server "dom02.net" -Identity $G.Name -Members $_ -Credential $creds -Verbose }`

Comment: You MUST use get-aduser from the source domainA if you want to add them to a target cross-forest DomainB group. I know, it sounds silly, but it's a requirement. When searching get-aduser you must specify the -server parameter targeting the source domain. If you do not do this, Add-ADGroupMember will fail because it cannot find such user (it doesn't know where to look back to the cross-forest domain!)

Comment: Ok. Did you try part 2 of my comment above? `-Identity` doens't support an array input like you tried, but sending the DNs through the pipeline should work.

Comment: Ok, this looks better, no errors. But, after running the script no users are added to the destination groups. Verbose shows "Performing the operation Set on target" to the correct corresponding groups, but nothing is added. It seems this is empty string: -Members $_    ?

Comment: Sure it's not just syncing? :-) Try just `$G.Members | Get-ADUser -Server ....` to see that it lists the users, then try again. The last part using `Add-ADGroupMember` is the same as your original solution except I run it once per user vs. all in on go (which from my experience can cause problems).

Comment: After removing everything after the Get-ADUser command, I can see output of all users.

Comment: Then it should work to add too. Are you sure it's not just slow syncing? The only difference between this and what you said worked (bugs excluded) is that you add `-properties:Distinguishedname` to the `Get-ADUser`-cmdlet. You can try it, but it shouldn't be necessary as it's a default property (always returned)

Comment: Working now :) I think it is slow syncing. I manually specified a domain controller that I was currently attached to in ADUC.msc and I now see the users correctly added to the groups. Thanks Frode!